# Difference between Google Speech Recognition and Google Cloud Speech API

Tags: python, google-api, google-speech-api

I haven't found anything online, though Python webpage https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/ clearly shows that there's a difference. I have been using Google Speech Recognition (not Google Cloud Speech API) without any API key and I am not sure whether it is okay to do so.